# How can I design an effective GUI for labels and values for an Android Tablet?

Tags: usability, gui-design, mobile, layout, design-patterns

I'm trying to create a simple GUI for an android application that will primarily be used on tablets. I have portrait and landscape screenshots of my current GUI. Note that this is literally the only screen that my application uses. I have no other information to display.

[image]
[image]

As you can tell, it's nothing special. There are normally buttons in the ActionBar to interact with the application, so I'm not worried about those. I'm mostly worried about displaying [Description]:[Value] more effectively on a large screen.

If you have any relevant tips, I would love to hear them. Most of my Google searching has resulted in designing web forms, which is not my goal in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the screen is just for displaying key-value pairs, then all your effort needs to go into making those easy to read. So include the values in your mock-up; without them, you can't check how it works.

Without making any radical changes, I've adjusted your landscape mockup a little bit:

1. I've pushed the text further to the centre; with a smaller gap between the key and the value, it makes left-right scanning easier on the eye i.e. more readable.
2. I've added faint guide-lines to separate each key-value pair; again, the idea of this is to make each key-value pair more readable.

   [image: mockup with improvements to help reading key-value pairs]

Other changes you might want to consider:

- Draw a table with alternate row-colouring; this is known to help guide the user's eye across tabular data.
- Instead of putting the values on the right, indent them and put them on the next row down under the key; this is a technique often used in small-screen apps where there isn't much horizontal space, and also has the advantage of keeping each value close to the key which again helps readable.

Answer (score 0):

If your primary target are tablets, consider having two/multi pane layouts. Don't just show one screen that contains only [Description] : [Value]. That way your pane that will contain the values will be much smaller and you won't have to worry about too much blank space.

As to how to display key/value pairs, Settings or People app are are place to start.

EDIT:
You might consider using PreferenceActivity as your main activity to get an Android default display.

Comment: The problem is that this is the only screen that my application has. There's literally no other information that I need to display at the moment. That's why I'm at a loss as to how to use all of the space.


Using a ListView to display key/value pairs was one of the things I looked into. I just simply wanted to know if there was a better solution. I kind of feel like using a ListView like in the following link might look funny.

http://joesapps.blogspot.com/2011/02/customized-listview-data-display-in.html

Comment: If this is the only screen you have, your GUI would be **Effective** in any case :) . Just make sure you add some healthy left/right margins to your activity when displayed in sw720dp-land.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a Card Layout, with cards of different size staggered. Much like what the Play Store is on a tablet. 
Each card could contain the property and value along with an icon.